# How to hide id in my html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i`m using spring boot with thymeleaf and i want to pass some values through form. One of the value i want to pass is "id" (to find object in my data base and update some value). However i realized, when i check the source of html page i can change "id" and save value to else id number. How i can hide my id ? (i need it to invoke method in controller). My code looks like this:

```
<form th:action="@{/set-value}" method="post" th:object="${carDto}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" th:value="*{id}" />
    <input type="text" th:field="*{value}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: _“However i realized, when i check the source of html page i can change "id" and save value to else id number”_ – and why is that a problem?

Comment: becouse i dont want to change that "id". I just need it to pass "id" to my method in controller. However i can open html page in my browser, open source code and type id myself.

Comment: Just because you “don’t want it”, doesn’t mean it actually is a real problem. And no, you can of course not “hide” information that is critical to the request; you can only substitute it with a different piece of information, like a token or a session id, that allows you to look up the corresponding id on the server.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving that information in the form of server-side encrypted cookie. That way, the user won't be able to change it to a valid other encrypted ID (unless they know your app's secret key and things like that). The user could still manipulate it, which might mean they could encounter an error while your server is decrypting the cookie, but that issue will be only for them and only because they tried to manipulate data and they won't be able to access any of the data that they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

you should really go for the PHP/back-end stuff for sensitive form data processing. However i tried to hide the id using javaScript/jquery but it doesn't really hide the id; anyone who has access to my javascript file can see the code easily.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
btn.addEventListener("click",myFun);

function myFun(){
    $("form input").attr("id","hello");
    console.log($("#hello").val());
    $("form input").removeAttr("id");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<form>
 <input type="text">
 <button id="myButton" type="button">Click</button>
</form>


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

check the developer tools when clicking the button.